# Programmatically fetch outlook properties in .net code

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I am trying to fetch the organizational seat number (a particular outlook field) from the outlook contacts properties, but I do not find any field for that.

I am able to fetch properties like name, organization address, location, email id etc. but there is no field for the seat number.

Here is the code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items OutlookItems;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookObj;
MAPIFolder Folder_Contacts;

outlookObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Folder_Contacts = (MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
OutlookItems = Folder_Contacts.Items;

for (int i = 0; i < OutlookItems.Count; i++)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem contact = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem)OutlookItems[i + 1];
    Console.WriteLine(contact.FirstName +"   "+  contact.OfficeLocation + "   "+contact.BusinessAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Checking from **list of outlook fields and properties** from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868508.aspx),
  looks like currently there is no field which would satisfy your requirement, i.e organizational seat number.
- Moreover, you could add **custom fields and data types**, so that users can add information such as your requirement - seat number. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868399.aspx) to know regarding custom fields and data types in outlook

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method exactly for getting the `organizational seat number` value. However, the required information can be stored as a custom property on an Outlook item. To observer all low-level property you may use any Extended MAPI property explorer tool such as MFCMAPI (open-source) or OutlookSpy (commercial).